# How to separate text in a single row that is in a heirarchy into separate cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following Heriarchy of text in one column different rows in excel

```
Text
  Text2
    Text3
      Text4
      Text5
```

[image]

I need to have this separate Text into Column A,  Text2 to column B, Text 3 to Column C and Text 4 and 5 to Column D while staying in their respective rows. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: That depends.  is the white space on the front spaces or indents?  If spaces simple formula will do, If Indents then one will need vba.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR : use another tool to help creating the 'tab' needed.

Long version :

1. Download notepad++
2. paste the text there
3. Find&replace > Replace "  " (double space) with "\t" (tab character)
4. salect all, copy n paste in excel

Done.

p/s : Click the if it helps. Or share us the printscreen error should you encounter one.